# Upload CSV to PowerBI with PHP

Tags: php, azure, powerbi

I want upload a CSV file to PowerBI. I've found lots of tutorials for C# or ASP.NET, but are not enough for me. Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no SDK in PHP to integrate PowerBI into your own server. But we can leverage PowerBI REST APIs to implement your requirements.

- Upload your CSV file to your PHP server
- Receive your data from CSV file and parse into json object
- Post the data to your PowerBI server via REST APIs.

You can get the PwerBI REST APIs references and the sandbox at http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/table-rows/add-rows-to-a-table-in-a-dataset

And you also can get the PHP sample for each the API in this link.

Comment: I see... I'm going to try how to get the token for it... Thaks!